# Delphi - Deleting an active/selected record of a ADO Table

Tags: database, delphi, ado

I'm trying to delete active/selected records from a TADOTable with an OnClick event of a TButton component. (I have multiple tabs with 1 TDBGrid with a connected TADOTable each)

Yet I'm not sure how I can do this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Kind Regards
PrimeBeat

Comment: Its just ``YourAdoTable.Delete``

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+13+Delphi+s+Database+Architecture/The+DataSet+Component/

Comment: This class is documented (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOTable) and given that you know the keyword is "delete", you can find the answer by looking for that word in the list of documented methods. Documentation and research are very powerful tools when used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender : TObject);
begin
    try
        AdoTable1.Delete;
    except
        on E:Exception do begin
            ShowMessage('Unable to delete record. ' + 
                        E.ClassName + ':' + E.Message);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: The exception handler is very poor indeed. Swallowing all classes of exceptions means that you might suppress unexpected programming errors rather than expected database errors. Also there is simply no need to handle the exception here. It can (and should) be handled by the application exception handling mechanisms.